# Getting an invalid_payload issue when trying to send a Slack notification on Google Sheets cell edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to get a noti on a Slack channel when a change is made on a cell in column L of a Google Sheet file. However, I keep getting issues with invalid_payload. Please help me review my code to see what was wrong.

```
var slackWebhookUrl = '';

function sendSlackMessage(message) {
  var payload = {
    'text': message
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebhookUrl, options);
}

function onCellEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  
  if (column == 12 && sheet.getName() == 'Form Responses 1') {
    var value = range.getValue();
    var row = range.getRow();
    var message = 'Cell L' + row + ' was changed to ' + value;
    sendSlackMessage(message);
  }
}
```

I tried to change the payload format, but the result was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your options have to be `"Content-type": "application/json"`? Yours is  `'contentType'`.

Comment: I changed my options into 'content-type': 'application/json' but I still got an error: 
"Exception: Request failed for https://hooks.slack.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: invalid_payload (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
sendSlackMessage @ Code.gs:14".

I added 'muteHttpExceptions': true into options, and now there is no error in the execution log when I run the code. And it does not send any noti in the Slack channel when I change the value on column L.

Comment: Is this the full error you get? I feel like there should be more.
Also is it deliberate that your `slackWebhookUrl ` is an empty string or will it actually get a value at some point? I feel like the answer might lie outside of what you've pasted here. What does the UrlFetchApp look like?

Comment: As for the *"it does not send any noti in the Slack channel when I change the value on column L"* - it's hard to say much, because there must be something calling your `onCellEdit` function. Do you have some Google Sheets webhook configured and a respective request handler implemented on your side?

Comment: I already set up a Slack app and pasted the webhook URL correctly.  It's really strange because I can use the URL to send a thread when the form is submitted. I don't know if onCellEdit is the correct function to be used.

Comment: You mentioned that "*I added 'muteHttpExceptions': true into options, and now there is no error in the execution log when I run the code*" - but did you log out the response regardless? It might not fail now, but might still respond with something useful. E.g.
`const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(slackWebhookUrl, options);` and then `console.log(response);`
Might have to look around the response body, to get something relevant.